# Writing a small C# application for bachelor thesis - Should I use MVC-Pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis about process optimization for creation of XML rendering Stylesheets for another application.
Therefore I am writing a very small and super basic software tool which displays XML structures in tree views. It enables the user to change those  (add and delete nodes) and to do some simple application specific stuff.

For doing that, I use Windows Forms.

My question is **if I should use a specific architecture** or design pattern like MVC or if it would be sufficient to only stick to basic patterns like factory method, command, observer etc. 
I am afraid that MVC would be overkill. But on the other hand I am afraid that I should make use of it as it is for a thesis...

The tool should only run on desktop. I don't think there will be any update after initial development.

Hoping for some toughs...

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't go for MVC pattern in a desktop application... this is a very opinion based question.

Comment: Personal opinion - MVC is often the way to go in my experience, especially if you want to be able to re-use your code in the future, or build upon /ontop of it. This project might start out small, but might very well become the foundation to something bigger in the future. I don't feel like MVC is overkill here, but what would be overkill would be to use EF6.

Comment: Professor suggested nothing. He is not that much into programming. Btw: I am not a computer science student - I study something that could be translated into "business systems". It's 75% software engineering, 25% economics. However, we never discussed how to program a _small_ application....

If I don't use MVC, should I use something else? Or just stick to the basic patterns stated above?

Comment: There are many routes to take here. Actually, for this purpose, i would just do a console-application, and not even bother with WinForms. You could easily generate a tree-structure in a console-application.

Comment: In your case I would suggest to develop the front end using WPF or UWP (Universal Windows Paltform), because they are both based on XAML, an XML language for creating .NET front ends. The MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern is more suited than MVC. There is also a lot of documentation about it, because it is widely used for mentioned technologies.

Comment: What about MVP pattern, look at this [article](https://markheath.net/post/model-view-presenter-winforms).

Comment: Nice article explaining MVVM pattern: https://www.wintellect.com/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained/

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here will involve opinion. I lean towards suggesting you don't worry too much, but rather try writing it in a way that makes sense to you then once you've got it working, take a look at whether there are any patterns out there that would improve your implementation.

Many of these patterns only make sense once you hit a certain scale with your program.

I'll add that WinForms has its own way of working that pre-dates much of modern MVC. You can shoe-horn it in, but it's not going to feel totally natural. This also factors into my suggestion that you first get your solution working, then explore options to tidy it up.

WPF might be a better fit for the kind of application you're building (`HierarchicalDataTemplate`), but the learning curve for WPF is very steep.

Of course if the people grading your work are looking for usage of patterns, then that's a different thing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are arguably two primary reasons for using a specific design pattern in this context:

1. You feel it it makes it easier for you to develop and maintain the code base (this is the main reason for using a design pattern in any context).
2. You feel it would reflect well on you and potentially improve your grade.

Regarding the first point, I assume the code you are writing is not a long term project. There are some exceptions to this rule (for example [this one)](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kutvonen/index_files/linus.pdf), but in general most thesis project codebases aren't maintained as long term software projects, even if concepts from them are re-used.

Regarding the second point, if you feel you can easily integrate the design pattern without writing more plumbing code for it than the code you are writing for your thesis, then it may help you express your concepts more clearly. However, if you feel it will be a larger distraction, and that you can build a high quality codebase without it, I would avoid being so opinionated, especially on a research project where the concept between inception and completion could change so drastically, and your professor may not care for "over-engineering".

If you have time, I would say the best thing to do is **get the thing working first**, and then decide if you could get value out of refactoring it into a specific design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your post!
It is point 2 for me. I never implemented something with MVC before.
Also **a very messy prototype of the application is already working** - it does everything well but the separation between logic and the forms is bad. 
In the prototype I am using ~10 controls. I never used interfaces.
We had many lessons about patterns, 4-tier-architecture etc. which is why I am afraid they want to see something like that